# Number of pairs of indexes of two arrays such that one element is greater than the other

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two arrays of size $n$. How many pairs of indices $i, j$ satisfy $1 \le i < j \le n$ and $A[i] > B[j]$?

After quite a bit of thinking the best i had gotten to was make a for loop inside of another, which i don´t think it´s a good solution. So i´d like to know some ideas on how to implement this algorithm more efficiently (possibly $O(n)$, if it´s possible).

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Hi Mateus can you also post input and output as an example for us, then it would be more easy for us to understand, just a sample input and output would be great. Like I want to know whether the array elements could be duplicates or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $A = B$, this is the same as counting the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Inversion_number), which can be accomplished in $O(n\log n)$ time using a [divide-and-conquer algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6523781/940550), and in $O(n\sqrt{\log n})$ time using more sophisticated techniques (see [Counting Inversions, Offline Orthogonal Range Counting, and Related Problems](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973075.15) by Chan and Pătraşcu).

---

In the other direction, here is how to solve a similar but not identical problem.

Given $A,B$, let us construct the following array:
$$
C := A[1],B[1],A[2],B[2],\ldots,A[n],B[n].
$$
An inversion in this array is one of the follows:

- A pair $A[i] > A[j]$ for $i < j$.
- A pair $B[i] > B[j]$ for $i < j$.
- A pair $A[i] > B[j]$ for $i < j$.
- A pair $B[i] > A[j]$ for $i < j$.
- A pair $A[i] > B[i]$.

Therefore you can deduce the number of $i < j$ such that either $A[i] > B[j]$ or $B[i] > A[j]$ given the number of inversions in each of $A,B,C$, augmented by the number of indices $i$ such that $A[i] > B[i]$. This yields a simple $O(n\log n)$ algorithm and a more complicated $O(n\sqrt{\log n})$ algorithm, as described above.

Comment: So what i need to need to do is find the number of inversions of the array $C$ and then subtract it from the number of inversion of $A$ and $B$, then finally subtract the number of indexes $i$ such that $A[i] >B[i]$. Did i get it right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Actually there´s another case you forgot, an inversion in the array C could also be a pair $B[i] > A[j], i <j$. So i need to subtract that quantity also, do you know how to count it?cause i don´t have any idea.

Comment: You can try varying the construction by perhaps adding more instances of each $A$ or of each $B$ in some non-symmetric way. Perhaps one such variation will help.

Comment: Another thing to try is to generalize the existing algorithms for counting the number of inversions to your setting, starting with the simple divide-and-conquer algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit heavy-weight, but: one way of thinking about this is as a series of spatial queries. If you conceptualise $B$ as a set of 2D points $(j, B[j])$ then you want to sum over $i$ the number of points $(j, B[j])$ in the quarter plane defined by $j > i$ and $B[j] < A[i]$.

You can build a 2D [range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) in $O(n \lg n)$ time and space, and each query then takes $O(\lg^2 n)$ (or maybe $O(\lg n)$ using fractional cascading: the Wikipedia article is a mess, and I haven't dug out the primary sources) for an overall running time of at worst $O(n \lg^2 n)$ and maybe $O(n \lg n)$.